# Can I Get list of MySql DBs from Ubuntu Command Prompt

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Is there any terminal command to know the MySql Databases existing on my Ubuntu server?

I know that I can check out/list all Sql DBs from within Sql by this: `SHOW DATABASES;`

But can we execute main-main MySql commands from Ubutnu Server Terminal command prompt, without entering Sql itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

echo "SHOW DATABASES;" | mysql -u ***user_name*** -p***password***

Comment: Thank you very much. Does that mean, I can use almost any mysql command this way? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, you are right. See also other possibilities: https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/MySQL_Beginner.html#zz-2.10